# Copy cell data to a new table row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to Excel VB scripting and i'm looking for information on how to copy specific cell data to a new sheet with a table and add a new line for each time you press the button to copy. Let me try to explain better
I have 1 sheet named **Values** and one named **Data**

***Excel Version 2013***

**Value Sheet Information**
in Cells A2, H17, H19, H21, H23, H25, H27, H29, H31, H33, H35 and H37

**Data Sheet**

Tablename: SurveyData
Table Header names
**AgeRange**, **B1**, **C1**, **D1**,**E1**, **F1**, and so on all on the same row

H17 = B1

H19 = C1

And so on

When you click on the button it should copy all these values from these cells to a new table row in the Data Sheet

I don't know how possible this is to do within Excel but i'm hoping there will be some options on how to perform this within Excel.

Thank you for taking your time and hope this explanation of mine makes sense.

Edit: I did a huge error when expressing my request, The data in the entry sheet is spread out across multiple rows and cells. I want to take these individual cells to be pasted into a new sheet on a new row. so it will look something like this

When you click the button it copies all data from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 each click creates a new row with data filled in on each cell that was copied from sheet 1 under their corresponding cell.

```
AgeRange  B  C  D  E  F  G
15-20     1  1  0  1  0  1
20-25     1  0  1  1  1  0
```

And so on.
I got the copy down but getting each individual cell to be pasted into one row in a new column and when done go to a new line for new data is the issue.

I do not know if i make any sense here

Regards

Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub CopySheet1PasteSheet2 ()

count=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(count+1,1) =Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,2)  'for A2

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(count+1,2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,5) 'for B5

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

In order to add next row you need to count rows in Data Sheet:

Dim count as integer;
count=Worksheets("Data").Cells(Worksheets("Data").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

To copy values from worksheets from A2 to V1
Worksheets("Data").Cells(count+1,1) = Worksheets("Values").Cells(1,2)

And then next cells accordingly

Comment: Thank you for a fast answer :D

Comment: Sorry, i did a huge misstake and i'm sorry I wrote my question very wrong. A note to self, not writing something when you have a fever. I have updated my request With the correct information since After i played around with your code i noticed that i had requested incorrect information.

Comment: Let's us say you have two cell ls A2 and B5 on Sheet1 and you want to paste data to Sheet.  Then your procedure should be like this: